# How to copy a file to multiple directories, PHP?

Tags: php, file, replace, copy, move

```
copy('foo/test.php', 'bar/test.php');
```

Above is the code which will transfer the **test.php** file from `foo` to `bar` and so overwrite any files if necessary.

I am trying to achieve the above but with several, undefined directories. How would I go about doing so?

**Overall**

- There are a bunch of directories in one location (an undefined amount)
- I need to replace the **test.php** files in those directories with the new one that has been copies from `foo`.

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: You can only have one destination for copy. Which means you need to call copy multiple times. It sounds like you could glob through the directory structure and copy the file to each one.

Comment: Use a loop where you do `copy('foo/test.php', $dir .  '/test.php')` with multiple values of `$dir`.

Comment: If all the destination files already exist, you could use `glob()` to find them all.

Answer (score 0):

as written you can pass one array in arguments and loops on it like that :

```
function fullCopy($oldDir = '', $newDir = []) {
    foreach ($dir as $value){
        if ( is_dir($oldDir && is_dir($newDir)) ) {
            copy( $oldDir . '/test.php', $newDir . '/test.php');
        }
    }
}
fullCopy('foo', ['bar', 'bar2', 'bar3']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but there is an undefined amount of directories around so how would I go about doing this so that it takes in all directories?

Comment: @Osman I think you can make use of php's `glob` function with `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag. Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php